# Golang gRPC stream XML file (server-side)

Tags: go, protocol-buffers, grpc, grpc-go, grpc-gateway

**The goal:** When I open `localhost:9000/xml` page in the browser I would like to see xml content (which is large). I use gRPC server with [grpc-gateway](https://github.com/grpc-ecosystem/grpc-gateway) as a proxy.

To send my xml file I use server-side stream and send `google.api.HttpBody` message with `text/xml` content-type. Below is a part of my server code for streaming xml:

```
reader := bytes.NewReader(data) // "data" is a large xml file
buffer := make([]byte, 1024)

for {
    n, err := reader.Read(buffer)
    if err == io.EOF {
        break
    }
    if err != nil {
        return status.Error(codes.Internal, "")
    }

    if err := stream.Send(&httpbody.HttpBody{
        ContentType: "text/xml",
        Data:        buffer[:n],
    }); err != nil {
        return status.Error(codes.Internal, "")
    }
}
```

Unfortunately when I open `localhost:9000/xml` in the browser I see that my xml response is broken. Every 1025 byte starts on a new line, for example:

```
...
...
<loc>https://example.com/books/1</l
        oc>
...
...
```

**How can I stream a large xml content and not break it?**

Comment: With this code, you are sending many httpbody messages, not one. Do not stream it and set the max msg size to something that will accept your XML data.

Comment: I have done it this way for now (I've increased sending size limit). You are right, I send many messages, but in DevTools there is only one response.